# Loop calls function which calls the SQL procedure, but the results don't display in HTML

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am running into a weird C#/HTML problem. I have a CSHTML file with the following code in it. On some of the production sites (but not all of them), it does not seem to be going through the loop. Looking at the HTML, there are no items in the list. My first impulse was that ListTags was not being called, but sniffing the SQL transactions shows that it calls the SQL function, and I can run that function on the database and verify that I get correct values. The only idea I have is that, for some reason, the statements in the first Razor code section are not all being called such that count never gets set above 0, but that seems unlikely.

```
<div>
    @{ List<String> stringList = Helper.ListTags(); int count = stringList.Count; int COL_WIDTH = 5;}
    <table style="width:100%">
        @for (int i = 0; i < count / COL_WIDTH; ++i)
        {
            <tr>
            @for (int j = 0; j < COL_WIDTH && i + j < count; ++j)
            {
                string tag = stringList[i * COL_WIDTH + j];
                string @tagId = "tag" + tag;
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value=@tag id=@tagId onclick='checkboxSelected(this)' />@tag
                </td>
            }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

The HTML that's being expressed on the servers in question is:

```
<div>
    <table style="width:100%">
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are no `<TR>`, `<TD>` or `<INPUT>` elements.

Comment: I don't believe we have enough information to tell you why it would be happening on some production servers and not others. If you don't have access to debug them, I'd suggest some logging mechanism to narrow down where the problem might be.

Comment: Why are you dividing count by col_width?

Comment: @Yohannes:
Because of screen real-estate, some aspects of which are fixed for dialogs due to how the system is designed, there needed to be multiple columns. I think I originally had a single loop and an `if` statement to mark the change in columns, but was required to change it for the sake of readability. And that's where the bug crept in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if your ListTags() method returns less than COL_WIDTH results, the condition in your first @for loop will fail at the first test.

Say ListTags() returns 4 entries. Count will be 4. The expression `i < count / COL_WIDTH` will return `false` as `count / COL_WIDTH` returns `0`.

Thus the outer loop never executes.

Try i ** <= ** count / COL_WIDTH

```
@for (int i = 0; i <= count / COL_WIDTH; ++i)
```

Furthermore, I think the condition in your second loop is incorrect.

Instead of `j < COL_WIDTH && i + j < count`, consider

```
j < COL_WIDTH && ((i*COL_WIDTH + j) < count)
```

Imagine ListTags() returns 7 items, and COL_WIDTH is still 5.

When i == 1 when rendering the second row, you want to stop the j loop after the second item. Your expression won't stop at j==2, as you are evaluating `(2 < 5) && (3 < count)` which isn't true.

Using the revised expression stops when i==1 and j==2 as you are evaluating `(2 < 5) && (1*5 + 2 < count)`, which is false.

Comment: If this is the expected behavior, you'd also need to fix the inner for loop condition so that you don't go past the end of the list. `i + j < count` should be `i * COL_WIDTH + j < count`.

Comment: Got there 10 seconds before me, James!

Comment: And the first condition would actually be checking for i < (count - 1) / COL_WIDTH so that it will only do a second row if there's more than COL_WIDTH items.